# Cross Browser solution for detecting video click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an 'editor' using JQuery. When I click my video element it should show my menu div. But it doesn't work on Firefox, it doesn't seem to be reacting to the click event code I have applied to it.

Any ideas how I can get my menu to show when you click my video on Firefox?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.my-widget').click(function() {
    $('.my-menu').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.my-widget * {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
.my-menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="my-menu">
<p>menu</p>
</div>
 
<div class="my-widget">
  <video controls="controls"><source src="https://storage.coverr.co/videos/Empire?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhcHBJZCI6IjExNDMyN0NEOTRCMUFCMTFERTE3IiwiaWF0IjoxNTc5MTUyMTk3fQ.C3WW6q97qHYspm5Hjn10mfbYCAfdR9jkm81QtNI2mF4"></video>
</div>

<div class="my-widget">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3445716/pexels-photo-3445716.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"/>
</div>

<p>Click the image or video to toggle the menu</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because browser does expose when users click on the controls of MediaElements, so you need to remove `controls` attribute from the `<video>` element:

```
<video controls="controls"><source="..."></video>
```